# Set Postfix and Dovecot mail server to store emails as 'vmail:vmail' user group

Tags: postfix, dovecot, roundcube

Please advise how to set Postfix and Dovecot mail server to store incoming emails with owner user and group vmail:vmail while currently it stores them as the mailbox owner user and group.
I tried to set

```
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

in /etc/postfix/main.cf (5000 is the uid of 'vmail' user),

```
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = vmail
```

in the /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf file and

```
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

in the /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext with no effect.

Comment: If the existing files have a different owner, change them yourself to what you expect. Then postfix and dovecot can operate on them with the vmail user

Comment: Then i would need to change owner of the incoming mail files every time i want to read the email which is about once a minute.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I configured it and it works for me:

On postfix master.cf file, add at the end:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

On dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf configure service auth on the following way:

```
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    group = vmail
  }
```

Hope it works for you. Regards